# Sidebar list: If current page is deepest level child, display sibling pages. If not, display child pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a sidebar that will display sibling pages if the current page is the deepest level child, and only child pages if it is not. This is as far as I've gotten, I haven't been able to figure out the logic to complete it. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
global $post; 
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $interior_sidebar = '<ul class="child-pages">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_list_pages() with your parameters to get children of current post. If it comes back empty then display wp_list_pages() of current post's parent; if not empty display what was returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

`global $post` isn't safe to use (it can be a post *other than* the page you are viewing), especially in a sidebar - I'd recommend doing something like [get_queried_item()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

And, to keep things simple, rather than calling `wp_list_pages` multiple times, I'd recommend setting up the arguments in each of condition, then having a single `wp_list_pages` call at the end.

```
// safer method to get the page you are viewing
$post = get_queried_object();
// will be TRUE if there's any child pages, FALSE if not
$has_children = (0 != get_pages( [ 'child_of' => $post->ID ] ) );
// set to prevent notices
$child_pages = FALSE;

if ( is_page( $post->ID ) && $post->post_parent ) {
    $args = [
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'title_li'    => '',
        'echo'        => 0,
        // this is a ternary operation, that assigns $post->ID if $has_children, or $post_parent if not
        'child_of'    => ( $has_children ) ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent
    ];

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( $args );
}

if ( $childpages ) {
    $interior_sidebar = '<ul class="child-pages">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}
```

*NOTE: I've used the shorthand version for array declarations (example, `[ 'child_of' => $post->ID ]` instead of `array( 'child_of' => $post->ID )` - this works for PHP versions 5.4+ - if you're on an older version of PHP, upgrade - it's not supported any longer*

Comment: Thanks! After changing `get_queried_item` to `get_queried_object`, that worked for the pages that are not the deepest level children. I still need to show sibling pages in the list on the pages that are the deepest level children though. Do you know how that could be accomplished?

Comment: The code above should do what you've asked.  What is the list that appears when you are at the deepest level?  (When you say deepest level, you mean there are no more children, correct?). NOTE that the code you provided ONLY shows anything if there are "parent pages" - so if you want this ALSO for "top level" navigation items, you need to clarify that so I can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {
    global $post;
    $childpages = wp_list_pages(array(
        'child_of'    => $post->ID,
        'depth'       => 1,
        'echo'        => '0',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'title_li'    => ''
    ));

    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string =$childpages;
    } else {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages(array(
            'child_of'  => $post->post_parent,
            'depth'     => 1,
            'exclude'   => $post->ID,
            'title_li'    => ''
        ));
        $string = $childpages;
    }

    echo $string; }
```

I then simply called the function in my template: `<ul class="child-pages"><?php wpb_list_child_pages(); ?></ul>`